# Geodesics on $\text{SL}_n$ with the Euclidean metric

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

$\newcommand{\Cof}{\operatorname{Cof}}$

Do we know how to calculate geodesics on $\text{SL}_n$ w.r.t the Euclidean metric?

More explicitly, I consider $\text{SL}_n$ with the Riemannian metric induced by the inclusion $i:\text{SL}_n \to (\mathbb{R}^{n^2},e)$. $e$ is the Euclidean metric; We take the pullback metric $i^*e$.

It seems to me straight segments between two different matrices never have constant determinant.

**Edit:**

This is wrong! Examples are given in [Andrew's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381529/geodesics-on-textsl-n-with-the-euclidean-metric#comment4910493_2381529). An interesting question is to characterize when a straight segment between a pair of matrices is a geodesic.

*Here is a partial result:*

Define $\alpha(t)=A+tB$. Then $\det \alpha(t)=\text{const}$ is equivalent to $$ 0=\frac{d \det \alpha(t)}{dt}=\langle \Cof (\alpha(t)), B \rangle.\tag{1}$$

Where $\Cof A$ is the cofactor matrix of $A$.
In the $2D$-case, $\Cof  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} d & -c \\\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}$, so if we take $A= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} ,B= \begin{pmatrix} \tilde a & \tilde b \\\ 
 \tilde c & \tilde d \end{pmatrix} $ we see that $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$ 0=\langle \Cof \begin{pmatrix} a+t\tilde a & b+t\tilde b \\\ c+t\tilde c & d+t\tilde d \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} \tilde a & \tilde b \\\ \tilde c & \tilde d \end{pmatrix} \rangle=\langle \begin{pmatrix} d+t\tilde d & -(c+t\tilde c) \\\ -(b+t\tilde b) & a+t\tilde a \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} \tilde a & \tilde b \\\ \tilde c & \tilde d \end{pmatrix} \rangle=\tag{2}$$

$$ (\tilde ad+a\tilde d)-(c\tilde b +b\tilde c)+2t(\tilde a \tilde d -\tilde b \tilde c)=0$$

So we must have $$ \tilde a \tilde d -\tilde b \tilde c=\det B=0, \tag{3}$$

and also $$\tilde ad+a\tilde d=c\tilde b +b\tilde c. \tag{4}$$

Condition $(3)$ means that the perturbation (or direction if the segment) must be singular. I do not know how to interpret the second condition. (If someone has a nice interpretation I would be happy to see it).

Comment: What does the Euclidean metric mean in this context? The induced Riemannian metric (induced from the standard embedding in $R^{n^2}&?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will make this explicit in the question.

Comment: @Asaf: The one parameter subgroups $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{array}\right]$ and $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ t & 1 \\ \end{array}\right]$ in $SL(2, \mathbf{R})$ are straight lines, so it's not "never". ;) (There are also hyperboloids of one sheet, which are doubly-ruled. I don't know about general geodesics, however.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks, you are right. Can you please elaborate on the hyperboloids? I do not see the connection. Thanks. Your comment also made me wonder if we can find a characterization of when the geodesic between a pair of matrices is a straight line.

Comment: Again in the $2 \times 2$ case,$$\det\left[\begin{array}{cc}a & b + c \\ b - c & d\\ \end{array}\right] = ad - b^{2} + c^{2} = 1.$$For each $k > 0$, the locus cut out by $d = ka$ and $ka^{2} + c^{2} - b^{2} = 1$ is a hyperboloid of one sheet, hence doubly-ruled. (In higher dimension one naturally gets further examples from coordinate permutations, but I'd expect there are even more.)